# How to remove duplicates with .RemoveDuplicates?

Tags: excel, vba

I have values in Column B of Sheet #1. I want to copy those values to a different sheet, then remove the duplicate values.

I have the following code:

```vb
tSheet.Range("B2:B" & tSheet.Range("B" & tSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy
tWb.Sheets("HELPER").Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Range("A1:A10").RemoveDuplicates
```

It is not removing the duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT#1:**

Replace:

```
Range("A1:A10").RemoveDuplicates
```

with:

```
tWb.Sheets("HELPER").Range("A1:A10").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
```

Comment: @soraia635  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: @soraia635  You are quite welcome! .......................I will "clean-up this answer later.